# Select only one checkbox out of three with same name

Tags: jquery, html

UPDATE:

My code now is something like this: (works).

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
         $("input:checkbox").click(function(){
var group = "input:checkbox[name='"+$(this).attr("name")+"']";
$(group).attr("checked",false);
$(this).attr("checked",true);
 });


          });
```

HTML:

```
     <input type="checkbox" name="swimming" class="chb" />
     <input type="checkbox" name="swimming" class="chb" />
     <input type="checkbox" name="swimming" class="chb" />
```

---

I have a questionnaire type form with three checkboxes for each question and I want the user to be able to select only one out of the three.

My HTML is something like this:

Question 1:

```
             <input type="checkbox" name="ballet" />
             <input type="checkbox" name="ballet" />
             <input type="checkbox" name="ballet" />
```

Question 2:

```
             <input type="checkbox" name="swimming" />
             <input type="checkbox" name="swimming" />
             <input type="checkbox" name="swimming" />
```

But this allows the user to select all checkboxes for a particular question. And I want it to be able to select only one out of the three. Is there a solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: Use radio-buttons instead?

Comment: What's wrong with radio buttons? I hate retarded designs like "here are checkboxes, but they don't work like checkboxes."

Comment: is there a way to make radio buttons look like native browser default checkboxes?

Comment: Yes but why bother? I see checkboxes and I expect multiple selection. It's like making a red X on a window that maximizes instead of closes.

Comment: true. but if the client gives you a design and wants that particular functionality in A checkbox, you can't really argue with the client.

Comment: " if the client gives you a design and wants that particular functionality in A checkbox, you can't really argue with the client." Yes. Yes, you can.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R7XTq/2/) here

```
$(':checkbox').on('change',function(){
 var th = $(this), name = th.attr('name'); 
 if(th.is(':checked')){
     $(':checkbox[name="'  + name + '"]').not(th).prop('checked',false);   
  }
});
```

As per the comment,  I assume user must be able to select one out of first three and 1 out of second three checkboxes. Because name attributes are different. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/m5EuS/554/) is demo.

```
 $("input:checkbox").change(function(){
 var group = ":checkbox[name='"+ $(this).attr("name") + "']";
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
     $(group).not($(this)).attr("checked",false);
   }
 });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m5EuS/1 > this works for me. But allows me to select two out of three and not one out of three. Can you help me with it? Unfortunately, your code does not work for me.

Comment: @AlexZahir And use `change` event until and unless checkboxes are replaced by images.. Because click will be fired in wrong way sometimes in IE.. `change` will be safe in this case.. And no difference regarding functionality too...

Answer (score 7):

You can try using a div.

```
 <div id="checkboxGroup">
<input type="checkbox" name="ballet" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ballet" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ballet" />
</div>

$('#checkboxGroup input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
if (this.checked) {
    $('#checkboxGroup input[type=checkbox]').not(
                        $(this)).prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcarvalhoxavier/kLFG4/)

Answer (score 3):

Radio buttons are the way to go. You can also preselect one of the options if you want by adding the word "checked" as an attribute within that input tag.

```
<input type="radio" name="ballet" value="1" checked />
<input type="radio" name="ballet" value="2" />
<input type="radio" name="ballet" value="3" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This is called an HTML radio button. Radio buttons are grouped together and the concept of a radio button is that only one at a time in a group can be selected.

The **name** attribute is the name of the group of radio buttons.

```
<input type="radio" name="ballet" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="ballet" value="2" />
<input type="radio" name="ballet" value="3" />
```

**Checkboxes with groups like radio buttons**

Notice that "x" is the class but that the "name" attribute is the group just like you've wanted.

```
$(".x").click( function() {
    var n = $(this).attr('name');
    $("[name=" + n + ']').prop("checked", false);
    $(this).prop("checked", true);
});

<input type="checkbox" name="swimming" class="x" />
             <input type="checkbox" name="swimming" class="x" />
             <input type="checkbox" name="swimming" class="x" />

<br/>

<input type="checkbox" name="diving" class="x" />
             <input type="checkbox" name="diving" class="x" />
             <input type="checkbox" name="diving" class="x" />
```

Comment: You mean you don't need jquery for mutually exclusive selection?!?!

Comment: LOL, if it's not jQuery, it's not JavaScript :) http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m5EuS/1/  > this works for me. But allows me to select two out of three and not one out of three. Can you help me with it? 
Unfortunately, your code does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

For Checkboxes:

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function () {
    $("[name="+$(this).prop('name')+"]").prop("checked", false);
    $(this).prop("checked", true);
});
```

You can use radios instead.

[`Fiddle For Checkboxes`](http://jsfiddle.net/LCX2g/3/)

Comment: This is gonna take forever as I have about a hundred checkboxes with a particular "name" attribute. I tried something like the code below but its not functioning correctly.

Comment: $("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    var group = "input:checkbox[name='"+$(this).attr("name")+"']";
    $(group).attr("checked",false);
    $(this).attr("checked",true);
});

Comment: You should give all of your checkboxes a common class and bind your events to that class for the event handler.

Comment: @PaulMendoza something like this:

 $(".chb").each(function()
               {
                   $(this).change(function()
                                  {
                                      $(".chb").attr('checked',false);
                                      $(this).attr('checked',true);
                                  });
               });

Comment: hey classes don't need .each function

Comment: @AlexZahir see this:http://jsfiddle.net/LCX2g/1/ I used `:checkbox` psuedo class in selectors.

Comment: @AspiringAqib your code works only if the checkbox name = swimming.